# PL/SQL Rollback

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

For insertion of records into database I created a PL/SQL script. In case of **any** error or exception I want to rollback all changes.

Is there a way to do this with: `WHENEVER [ERROR] EXIT ROLLBACK;` ?

I'm aware of:

```
declare
  ...
begin
  ...
exception when OTHERS then
  rollback;
end;

commit;
```

but I'm using several anonymous blocks, and don't want to do the exception handling several times.

Comment: It would be `whenever SQLERROR exit rollback`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
declare
  ...
begin
  ...
  do something that can go wrong
  ...
  commit;
exception when OTHERS then
  rollback;
end;
```

Comment: I'm using several anonymous blocks, and don't want to write the source for Transaction handling several times.

Comment: Did you try just to exit the procedure without any exception handling? For my understanding nothing is changed in the database until you COMMIT explictly.

Comment: as user3767013 said, you can just - do nothing, and oracle automatically rolls back all transactions since last successful commit. it works.